# How am I able to fix this code when I try to add a dictionary key and value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am having trouble with one bit of my game where I move nested dictionaries from one to another.
This is my code so far

```
player_inventory_weapons = {
"0": {"Name ": "Basic sword", "Sharpness": 10, "Fire level": 0, "Poison": 0, "Resistance 
addition": 5, "type": "weapons"}   
}

player_equip_weapons = {   

}

# move item from one dicionary to another

def equip():
    inp = str(input("What item would you want to move over? ")) # input number that is the key of what you are trying to equip
    if inp in player_inventory_weapons:
        del player_equip_weapons  #only one allowed at a time
        player_equip_weapons[inp] = player_inventory_weapons[inp]
        del player_inventory_weapons[inp]
equip()
```

When I try to equip the 'Basic sword" by inputting '0', it gives me the error 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'player_equip_weapons' referenced before assignment'
I've already tried multible things but none of them have worked! If you can help that that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no need for `str()`. `input()` always returns a string.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why are you trying to `del` it in the first place? What does "only one allowed at a time" mean?

Comment: Like I only want one item equipped at a time, so in my head I thought that using del to delete the previous value of player_equip_weapons to ensure that there would only ever be one value inside of it, silly now that Barmar brang up the fact that I don't need a dictionary and can instead use a variable

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete the variable, just empty the dictionary with the `clear()` method.

```
def equip():
    inp = input("What item would you want to move over? ") # input number that is the key of what you are trying to equip
    if inp in player_inventory_weapons:
        player_equip_weapons.clear()  #only one allowed at a time
        player_equip_weapons[inp] = player_inventory_weapons[inp]
        del player_inventory_weapons[inp]
```

Although I'm not sure why you would use a dictionary if it can only have one item at a time. Just make the variable hold the item.

Answer (score 0):

This is your basic problem:

```
del player_equip_weapons  # This line deletes the variable
player_equip_weapons[inp] = player_inventory_weapons[inp]  # This line tries to access a variable that doesn't exist
```

Because you're deleting the variable, your attempt to access it will fail.

Note that you almost never want to use `del` or global variables. Rather, do something like this:

```
def equip(inventory: dict):
    inp = input("What item would you want to move over? ")
    item = inventory.pop(inp, None)
    if item is not None:
        return {
            "hand": inventory.get(inp, "Nothing")
        }
    else:
        print("No such item in your inventory!")
        return dict()

player_equipped_weapons = equip(player_inventory_weapons)
```

This overwrites the equipped weapons variable with the result of your equip function. In this manner, you don't need to worry about clearing the original dictionary. And rather than use `del` you can use `pop()` to remove the item from your inventory data, which lets you then check to see if that item actually existed there.